# Git Subtree pull and automatically commit the merge

Tags: git, terminal, scripting, git-merge, git-subtree

How can I do a git subtree pull and automatically commit the merge?

Here's how I call subtree pull:

`git subtree pull --prefix Utils UtilsRepo master --squash`

The issue is that this often opens up the vi editor in the Terminal that I just entered the command (I'm on OSX). And then I need to enter ":q" in order to close it again. Since I have multiple subtrees and I want to pull all in a sequence, it's quite annoying to enter ":q" after various pulls.

How to automate this?

Comment: `GIT_EDITOR=true git subtree pull --prefix Utils UtilsRepo master --squash`

Comment: Thanks, what does this do?

Comment: It runs your command `git subtree pull --prefix Utils UtilsRepo master --squash` with the environment variable `GIT_EDITOR` set to program `true` which is `/bin/true`. When Git needs to run an editor it checks the environment variable and runs the given program with a filename (saved commit message). The program `/bin/true` simply returns and Git gladly accepts the unchanged message from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you want to perform any sort of merge without opening the editor to describe the message, set the `GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT` environment variable to `no`.  For example, I have this in my shell configuration, but if you want it only in this case, you could use an alias.

Comment: Thanks, do I just add a `GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT` = no line?

Comment: If you put it in your shell configuration, you'll need to write it like this `export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no`.  You can't add additional spaces around the equals sign, and the `export` is required.